# DD-WRT as wireless access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Helllo,
I'm trying to use my dd-wrt router as a wireless access point. I've succesfully set that up, but in trying to use it for my xbox 360 to connect to my main network (xbox doesn't come with wireless card, so I'm using the dd-wrt as a wireless access point.

The xbox is able to connect to the internet without problem, but is running in the 192.168.2.x range and is unable to work with my media center pc which is in the 192.168.1.x range.

Is it possible to get these two working on the same subnet? I'd really like to get the media extender running without dumping all the $$ into a wireless adapter.

Comment: You probably just need to make sure both are set to use DHCP and restart them so they'll get a address from your router in the same subnet.

Comment: Are you using the stock firmware on the dd-wrt?

Comment: dd-wrt is not stock, am I right?
Just buffalo and other few have it stock afaik...

Comment: You are right, I was thinking of the specific router models that run dd-wrt, not the fact that it was the firmware itself.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off DHCP server on the router you have connected to your xbox and assign it an IP address in the same subnet as your first router (first router should be 192.168.1.1 and make the second router 192.168.1.2).  Under advanced routing on the second router switch the operating mode from gateway to router.

From this point you have several options to connect your second router to your first router wirelessly.  You can use Client Bridge, Repeater Bridge, or WDS.  If you just plan on using the second router as wireless adapter for your xbox then a Client Bridge would be the best way as it is the most efficient (data is not double transmitted like WDS and Repeater Bridge which are very similar).  If you do need other devices to connect to your second router then you can do set it up as a Repeater Bridge or use WDS.  Instructions links below.

[Client Bridge Instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge)

[Repeater Bridge Instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge)

[WDS Instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WDS_multiple_router_setup)

[Repeater Bridge vs. WDS Comparisons](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeating_Mode_Comparisons)